# How to compare date in linq c#

Tags: c#, json, linq, datetime

i have 'created date' and 'closed date' in my file and i'm converting it in json so i have that dates in json.
in  my  method i have two parameter like from date and to date and i want to count particular column data of my file between from date and to date.so how can we write code to fetch it using linq.

i tried this...

```
public JsonResult StatusDerails(DateTime from,DateTime to)
{
        string csvurl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["csvfileurl"];
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvurl).Skip(1);
        List<Product> prdt = new List<Product>();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Product c1 = new Product();
            var split = line.Split(',');
            c1.ID = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
            c1.Area_Path = split[1];
            c1.IterationPath = split[2];
            c1.State = split[3];
            c1.Reason = split[4];
            c1.Priority = Int32.Parse(split[5]);
            c1.Severity = split[6];
            c1.Tags = split[7];
            c1.Title = split[8];
            c1.CreatedDate = split[9];
            c1.CreatedBy = split[10];
            c1.ResolvedDate = split[11];
            c1.ResolvedBy = split[12];
            c1.ClosedDate = split[13];
            c1.AssignedTo = split[14];
            prdt.Add(c1);
        }

        //var list = prdt.GroupBy(a=>a.AreaPath).Select(a=>new UIproduct() {

        var productName = prdt.Select(a => a.Area_Path).Distinct();
        List<StatusDetail> statusdetail = new List<StatusDetail>();
        foreach (var Name in productName)
        {
            StatusDetail sd = new StatusDetail();
            sd.CarryOver = prdt.Where(a => a.CreatedDate >= from.Date.ToString() && a.ClosedDate <= to.Date.ToShortDateString               
        }
        return Json(statusdetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: As a suggestion: Don't parse the csv by hand, there are good libraries to do exactly that. I personally like kbcsv, but that's just one of a lot of options.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison of DateTime as string will not be a good option and that wont gives you the exact result, So I recommend you to change the type of `CreatedDate` and `ClosedDate` to DateTime. and compare two DateTime values in linq. I think **instead of splitting json for creating object of certain types you can use json converters.**

Fix for your scenario:

```
c1.CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(split[9]);
c1.ClosedDate = DateTime.Parse(split[13]);
```

Don't forget to change the type in the class, Now its fine to use the linq as like the following:

```
sd.CarryOver = prdt.Where(a => a.CreatedDate >= from.Date && a.ClosedDate <= to.Date);
```

Comment: while adding c1.CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse(split[9]);
c1.ClosedDate = DateTime.Parse(split[13]); am getting error : cant convert datetime to string

Comment: instead of passing parameter in method i'm manually seted date like     string from = "06 - 06 - 2017 00:00:00";
            string to = DateTime.Now.ToString();